# UIButton going behind Tab Bar when navigating back to parent View Controller - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have 2 `UIButton`s that I have placed on my `TabBarViewController`, (there are Navigation Controllers embedded too).

In the last ViewController (in navigation Controller stack), I have to hide the tab bar, and I have achieved that successfully.

The issue is, when I navigate back to the `parentViewController`, the `UIButton` goes behind the tab bar (see GIF Image below):

**The red record button and red "Preserve" button are the `UIButton`, and are not `tabBarButtons`**

[image: GIF]

This is how I'm adding the `UIButtons` in my `tabBarViewController`:

```
self.button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(recordButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.button1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
self.button1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[self.button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_record"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
    self.button1.center = self.tabBar.center;
else
{
    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0 - 0;
    self.button1.center = center;
}

[self.view addSubview:self.button1];
```

The other red "Preserve" button is also added with a similar code as above.

Now in my last `navigationViewController`, I'm hiding the `tabBar` by the following code:

```
#pragma mark - Overriden UIViewController methods, this function gets called automatically when viewController is loaded
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
    return YES;
}
```

The above function's returning `YES` hides does the tabBar, but its the one thats making the buttons go behind tabBar on going to previous View Controllers.
If I change it to `NO`, then the buttons don't go behind `tabBar`, but also `tabBar` does not hide on the last `viewController`.

Please suggest a way to either hide tabBar with a different way, or bring those `UIButton`s to front.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, found the solution! instead of hiding the `tabBar` by

```
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
    return YES;
}
```

hide the `tabBar` by `[tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES]` in the last `viewController`. Then when navigate back, do `[tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];` in `viewWillDisappear`.

This way the `subviews` arrangement in `tabBarController` stays same :)

Comment: Thanks! This fixed our exact same issue with a button being hidden by the tabbar only when navigating back.

Answer (score 1):

Add below method in your custom tabbar controller to fix the issue of your custom button go behind the tabbar.

Objective-C Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.centerButton != nil) {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.centerButton];
        for (UIView *vw in self.view.subviews) {
            if ([vw isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]){
                if(vw.hidden){
                    self.centerButton.hidden = true;
                }
                else {
                    self.centerButton.hidden = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Swift Code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if self.centerButton != nil {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.centerButton)

        for vw in self.view.subviews {
            if let subView = vw as? UITabBar {
                if subView.isHidden == true {
                    self.centerButton.isHidden = true
                } else {
                    self.centerButton.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's just a little slow, there is a delay of about 0.5 seconds when the view changes from hide to show or show to hide.

Comment: answer has already been provided 1.5 years back. If you find it useful please upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: If user can hide show in **viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear**
(self.tabBarController as? CustomTabbarViewController)?.centerButton?.isHidden = **false/true**.

centerButton is working perfect withou 0.5 second delay time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bring the buttons front when the view layouts?

For example

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.button1)
```

Or instantiate it above the tabBar

```
self.view.insertSubview(self.button1, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried @Sha answer and additionally this is what I did to run it **successfully**.
Make sure you add this code in **Last ViewController**

```
var tabbarViewController: tabbarViewController?
var tabbarHoldonFrame = CGRect()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.hideTabbar()
    }
    func hideTabbar() {
        // get instance of tabbar controller
        tabbarViewController = self.navigationController?.tabBarController as? tabbarViewController
        // hide tabbar
        tabbarViewController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        // hide your additional button placed above tabbar
        tabbarViewController?.buttonCreateContest.isHidden = true
        // hold it's frame in tabbarHoldonFrame, set zero temporarily 
        tabbarHoldonFrame = (tabbarViewController?.tabBar.frame)!
        tabbarViewController?.tabBar.frame = CGRect.zero
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.showTabbar()
    }
    func showTabbar() {
        // show it
        tabbarViewController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        // show your button
        tabbarViewController?.buttonCreateContest.isHidden = false
        // add default frame
        tabbarViewController?.tabBar.frame = tabbarHoldonFrame
    }
```